# How to connect already connected table with other table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have a user table it has one userRole and userRole belongs to Role. So, I want to fetch the userRole and Role also.

Code in user Model:

```
public function userRole()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserRole::class);
}
```

Code in UserRole model:

```
 public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

Code in controller:

```
User::with('userRole', function ($role) {
  $role->with(['Role']);
})
->wherehas('userRole', function ($query) {
     $query->where('role_id','1');
 })->get();
```

This is giving me error

> "mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should pass an array when you want to add a constrait to the `with()` method.

Your code should like something like:

```
User::with([
    'userRole' => function ($query) {
        ...
    }
])
...
```